# finding a specific element at the end of line with regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

There is a specific file and the names are marked for each student alongside his/her grade at the end. I have to check if it equals B and then print B. However I am getting more B due to the possible choice of names being included to increment in B's value.

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
        

                 # YOUR CODE HERE
    pattern = r"[B$]"
    result = re.findall(pattern, grades)
    return result
    raise NotImplementedError()
    
x = grades()
print(x)
```

James:  B
Stuart: B
Binny  : A
Billy : A

I am getting more than 2 Bs. WHAT i should get is 2 Bs. What i am doing wrong in the code above?

Comment: You need `pattern = r"(?m)B$"`

Comment: thanks! what i should be doing more in order to get used to regex library? It is compartively tough for a beginner like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches either `B` or a `$` char.

You need

```py
pattern = r"(?m)B$"
```

where

- `(?m)` - an equivalent of `re.M`/`re.MULTILINE` flag that makes [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) match start/end of lines, not whole strings
- `B` - matches a `B`
- `$` - now, matches the end of a line.